# df into lists name based on column values in R

Tags: r

I have dataframe need to convert into lists, names of lists based on column

```
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("John", "Dora", "Dora", "Dora"), "V3" = c("Some text", "Some text 1","Some text 2","Some text 3"),  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So far I tried

```
df.list <- split(df, seq(nrow(df)))
```

but this convert into lists separately based on rows

What is required some thing like

```
df.list <- structure(list(`John` = structure(list(V3 = structure(1L, .Label = "Some text", 
                                                               class = "factor")), .Names = "V3", row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
                        `Dora` = structure(list(V3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Some text 1", 
                                                                                         "Some text 2",
                                                                                         "Some text 3"), 
                                                               class = "factor")), .Names = "V3", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("John", "Dora"))
```

Comment: `as.list(df)`. Data frames are already lists internally, with each column being a different list.

Comment: Just use `split(df['V3'], df$Name)`

Comment: ya but I want to keep the above structure because i have code/function that would apply only with that structured.

Comment: @akrun ya i tried that as well but does not include levels

Comment: It is based on the expected output.  What do you meant by not include levels?

Comment: I dont know how to express more precisely but Dora must show as factor w/ 3 levels as shown in "df.list"

Comment: @Janjua Sorry, I didnt check the type of `df.list` earlier.  It is better to have as `character` class instead of `factor`.  Are you doing some analysis that requires `factor` class

Comment: Ya i understand your point, i was trying some function but could not make it thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's columns were `character` class in the initial dataset.  If we need to have an output `list` with `factor` columns, then use `as.factor/factor` to convert after the `split` or before

```
lst <- lapply(split(df['V3'], df$Name), transform, V3 = factor(V3)) 
all.equal(lst, df.list[names(lst)], check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```